# Displaying multiple paperclip images from database in ROR app. many relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreign-keys, paperclip, relationship

I'm very new to ROR and I'm  building an ROR app where each product can have many images.
Im using `paperclip`for the image upload.

To do that I added an `image.rb` model to the app and now the `product.rb`model `has_many :images` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :images`.

That is all working fine with out problems.

The thing is that  the `product.rb` model have this relations `belongs_to :category` and `belongs_to :label`

and `category` and `label` both `has_many :products`

Before I added the `image.rb` model each product had one picture attached to it.
and at the `index.html.erb`page the user could see categories lined up, with the latest uploaded picture from each product in category as the front picture for each category.

Below is the snipped I used to show the categories at `index.html.erb` before I added the `image.rb`model.

```
<div class="container-fluid">

        <% @products.each_slice(3) do |products_group| %>
        <div class="row">
          <% products_group.each do |category, products| %>

                <% products.each_with_index do |product, index| %>
                    <% if index == 0 %>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 center-block " >

                        <%= link_to category_path (category), { :method => 'GET' } do %>
                            <%= image_tag product.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive" %>
                        <% end %>
                <div class="caption">
                    <p class="category-name" ><%= product.category.name %></p>
                 </div> 
                <% end %>
                <% end %>
                </div> 
            <% end %>
            </div>
        <% end %>

</div>
```

And in the `pages_controller.rb` there was this code:

```
 def index   
   @products = Product.all.order(created_at: :desc).group_by(&:category_id)
 end
```

As seen in the code samples above I´m grouping products based on their categories, and then I'm showing each category that have any products at the index page. The category shown on the index page shows only the latest uploaded product  in each category.

But now after I have the `image.rb`model to handle the photo upload I need a way to show the same result at the index page but when the user hits some category he is taken to that category page.

It is a problem because now the images are bound to the `image.rb` model but not the `product.rb` model anymore.

I can see the uploaded pictures in the `image.rb`model  but I'm not sure how I should adjust the relations with out breaking everything.

Can someone please help me?

below are the models involved:

`product.rb`

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_list :scope => [:category, :label]
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :label

  has_many :images
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images
  has_many :product_items, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

the `category.rb`

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :products, :dependent => :nullify

   extend FriendlyId
   friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]

end
```

and the `image.rb`

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :product

    has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "500x500#", thumb: "100x100#" }
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/

end
```

Comment: If your aim is just to display image from latest product then you can try something like `product = @products.first` and then `<%= image_tag product.images.first.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive" %>`

Comment: thanks for your suggestion @Abhinay but it gives me the error `undefined local variable or method 'product' for #<#<Class:0x007fe0bc2e02a8>:0x007fe0bc2d3a80>
Did you mean?  product_url
               @products`

Comment: @Abhinay I think @codegirl is asking about how see can manage to keep the same function in the `loop` on the index page as she had before she added the `image`model. But the difference now is how she is going to display the first image  for  the latest uploaded product in each category..

Comment: Before you have one image in each product. And now you have many images in a product. I think you just need to iterate before image_tag --> product.images.each do | image | and so on.

Comment: thank you @PapayaLabs Are you talking about putting another loop inside the `each` loop?..could you maybe set it up as an answer? I'm not 100% sure how to do it or what you mean :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you have one image in each product. And now you have many images in a product. I think you just need to iterate before image_tag:

Before:

```
<%= image_tag product.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive" %>
```

After:

```
<% product.images.each do |image_model| %>
  <%= image_tag image_model.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive" %>
<% end %>
```

If you want to show the first picture:

```
<% if product.images.first %>
  <%= image_tag product.images.first.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thank you, I get it ,  but if I add this solution, I get this error `undefined method 'url' for #<Image:0x007fe0b9fc8770>
Did you mean?  URI`

Comment: Sorry is image_model.image.url, I put image_model to be different from image field, I change the answer

Comment: Hi again @Papaya Labs, there is one small problem.... all pictures for each product is showing.   For example I added two pictures for one product in one category and they are both showing.... instead of showing just one.  I tried to add `.first` to the code but that breaks the app

Comment: But why is one. Where is define it that you want to show that picture?

Comment: How the program know what are the pictures you want to show of a specific product?

Comment: I think you need to define some field in Image model where you define this.

Comment: because this is what is shown at the index page, the user sees category... and in that category is a products. On the index page the category is only showing one picture for the latest product in that category. Then the user clicks the category and see all products in the category

Comment: That is beyond my knowledge t o define that... don´t know what to do

Comment: I edit the answer. Maybe that help you. Is to show the first image only

Comment: thank you but sorry, that gives me this error `undefined method 'image' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: You replace the entire loop for the line?

Comment: If you want the first picture only do not make a loop, just replace one line for the other

Comment: Also you need to make sure that the product has one picture. I edit answer

Comment: Yes I replaced the `<%= image_tag product.images.first.image.url(:medium), class: "img-responsive" %>` for the entire loop and get this error `undefined method 'image' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: And you need to make sure that the product has a least one picture. I edit the answer

Comment: YEssssss...... Now this is working like a charm.... thank you so much :D I'm constantly learning new things ;D